# Master DB - Local DB- 10,000+ client sync

Tags: sql-server, architecture, synchronization

I have a project where there will be a master source database, client windows service, client application, client database.
We need to have a client database because there are times when the client won't be able to reach out to the master database source due to connectivity issues.

I was hoping to get some of your expertise on what would the best/most efficient way to sync certain tables from client database to master database and other tables from master database to client database in close to real-time (within minutes). I would also need to keep track of what was synced in the master database so that I can use it in a dashboard. 
There could be up til 10,000 + clients trying to pull this information all at once.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: [Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Does replication work well with offline/online sync?

Comment: Read the docs to see if it meets your requirements.

Comment: You should probably look at this framework : https://www.github.com/mimetis/Dotmim.Sync I'm the author. It was inspired by the Sync Framework at the very beginning, but now it's a complete new framework, easier to usen with a lot of great features :)
It's full .Net Standard 2.0, so compatible with .Net fx 4.8+ and .Net Core 2.1+
You can sync MySql, Sql Server or Sqlite. Let me know if you need assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in a scheme based on [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org) technologies.

Apache Kafka has the ability to create [connectors](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html).

The architectural scheme will look like this:

```
Local DB - Connector - Apache Kafka - Connector - Server DB.
```

Connectors support different databases.

You can use connectors to connect to the database itself or to separate tables.

Your scheme is similar to the [ETL scheme based on Apache Kafka technologies](https://www.confluent.io/blog/building-real-time-streaming-etl-pipeline-20-minutes/).

You can also develop an application that will track what was synced in the main database using [Apache Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/).

The other way, if you don't use Apache Kafka, is to [master - master replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-master_replication).